# If a real polynomial of degree $n\gt 1$ has a root of modulus exceeding all others, is that one a real root?

Tags: linear-algebra, integration, complex-analysis

Suppose $a_nx^n+\ldots+a_1x+a_0=0\; (a_n\in \mathbb{R})$ has $n$ distinct roots $r_1,r_2,\ldots, r_n$ (no multiple roots),
and if $\exists r_k$ s.t. $\forall r_i\in\{r_1,r_2\cdots r_n\}-\{r_k\}$, $|r_k|>|r_i|$,
then $r_k$ is real root?

Please give a counter-example or  a proof, I really thank you.

Comment: Your phrasing of the Question is hard to follow.  The title mentions "model" twice, but model of an equation or a root is not a familiar concept.  Looking at the body of the Question, you seem to be asking if the root of largest absolute value is necessarily real.  Apparently you assume the roots are complex, but you should be clear about the field that contains the roots and the coefficients $a_i$.  Also, just because the roots are distinct does not compel distinct absolute values.  Indeed $n$ distinct complex roots might all have the same absolute value.

Comment: I'm guessing "model" in the title should be "modulus", and will edit accordingly.

Comment: Has the polynomial real coefficients?

Comment: Sorry for my poor English.And $a_n$ is real coefficient, I have correct it .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The conclusion that a unique root of largest modulus (absolute value) is real will follow *if* it is assumed that coefficients $a_i$ are real.  The proof is simply that complex roots of real polynomials occur in conjugate pairs, so if the "largest" root is of unique absolute value, that one must be real (otherwise a complex conjugate root would exist, and have equal absolute value).

On the other hand if the coefficients are taken merely to be complex values, the conclusion will not follow.  An arbitrary complex root of largest absolute value may be chosen, picking the other $n-1$ roots to be any distinct complex numbers of smaller absolute value.

Comment: I am sorry for my omit.Expressing my question is hard for me ,but your answer is what  I need ,thank you .